# Javascript href link not working outside of the menu

Tags: javascript, html, href

I'm editing a website and I can't get it to work properly. I'm using a responsive menu to go between pages (stays in the same page but changes out the page elements). The code for it is [here](http://pastebin.com/0ttnDTXb).

Now I'm trying to include a link in the text of the page (as opposed to just in the menu)
[Here](http://pastebin.com/cViNn8Mp) is the code for that plus the menu.

The link won't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. Please isolate the issue, post your code in the question, explain what you tried to fix it, what didn't work, and post a demo to reproduce the issue at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Please try to make a sscce: http://www.sscce.org/ By doing that you will get far better responses and help.